# WB network-wide leaderboard not displaying the profile pictures of the top users

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, winterbash-leaderboard

The [network-wide leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) on the Winter Bash page does not appear to display the profile pictures of the top users. Rather, it seems to be displaying users at random, some with no hats at all.

[image]