# Winter Bash main leaderboard page displays the wrong avatars next to the network-wide leaderboard listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021, winterbash-leaderboard

On the [Winterbash 2021 Leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) page, the avatars displayed next to the link to "The Stack Exchange Network – Network-wide leaderboard" are not accurate:

[image: Screenshot of the row in the leaderboard page for "The Stack Exchange Network – Network-wide leaderboard", showing a set of 5 seemingly arbitrary users' avatars on the right]

For comparison, here are the top users shown on the [network-wide leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) (as of now):

[image: A list showing the user's rank in the leaderboard, their avatar, username, number of hats, and images of 9 of the hats they've earned – #1: Ankit Sharma, 9 hats; #1: José Carlos Santos, 9 hats; #3: Suraj Rao, 8 hats; #3, user17242583, 8 hats; #5, double-beep, 7 hats; #5, Thomas Markov, 7 hats; #5, Dharman, 7 hats]

Shouldn't the position #1 above show the avatar of any one of #1 in the ranking (that is, Ankit Sharma or José Carlos Santos) and similarly for other positions too? Or is it intentional that it is displaying random users' avatars?

The specific site's leaderboard (for example, [SO's leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com)) and [SE leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) displays avatars according to ranking.

Comment: I saw the same issues, wanted to ask this but then on some refresh ti got fixed but now it's back again with the same issue with different avatars. Mouseover show it's not only avatar but wrong user is linked there

Comment: @AnkitSharma Happened to me a few moments ago, I reloaded the page and it got fixed and gain reloaded, they were correct but reloading it for the third time made the section display random avatars.

Comment: yeah it's very repetitive big

Comment: This is the most famous I will ever be. I have peaked.

Comment: The hat shown here is the one I am wearing only in SO.. Not in MSE

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Lucky, you'll probably be there for longer than fifteen minutes.

Comment: This was [also an issue in last year's Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357946/wb-network-wide-leaderboard-not-displaying-the-profile-pictures-of-the-top-users) but wasn't fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query that retrieves this information wasn't accounting well for differences between "total different Hat Count" **per-site** and **network-wide**. I've pushed an adjusted version of the query that should account well for those.

Thanks for reporting! Appreciate the help.